# Get printf on Console.app

Tags: macos, printf, osx-mountain-lion

On Mac OS 10.7 I was able to see the printf of my application in Console.app.

However it seems that it is not the case on 10.8.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2208237/1393890) is mentioning that Console can be sandboxed and that you can change this by editing the plist of syslod.
However, the plist format seems to be different on 10.8 and I did not find anything relate to sandbox.

Does anyone knows if there is a way to change this.

Thanks in advance.

Kevin

Comment: Is your question how to get printf to output to the Console, or how to change the plist format related to sandboxing Console? On 10.8, Console is not sandboxed by default.

Comment: @Merlin069: my question is to get printf in the Console. I just mentioned that sandbox thing because this is the only information I have found so far.

Comment: Is your application in a bundle, or ist it a terminal app?

Comment: @Merlin069: It is a bundle.

Comment: Ok, do you specifically need to use printf, or can NSLog do what you want?

Comment: I use printf because it is portable so I can see them on both Windows and Mac OS. What would be the benefit of NSLog?

Comment: As you'd tagged osx-mountain-lion and not Windows, I did not know that you needed to be cross platform. NSLog logs to the Console window.

Comment: this is was just the way I was working before. But I will probably have to change this, since printf are no longer printed into Console