# Handling errors/exceptions & logging them in iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nserror, nsexception

I wanted to know do we need to log the exceptions/errors in a common file in file system when an iPhone application runs for debugging purpose later point in time? Or this is handled by IOS automatically through device logs?

I now using NSLog statements we can print on consol but is there something similar to log4j in Java where you put all debugging statements including errors/exceptions in a single file which you can analyze later point in time.

What is the best way to handle such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Some excellent info is found in this previous post on SO:

[Logging to a file on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202299/logging-to-a-file-on-the-iphone)

Another good tip for logging in general is using the DLog macro:

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/the-evolution-of-a-replacement-for-nslog