# Customised NSLog generate error when I pass [<object> description] as parameter

Tags: ios, nslog

I have followed [How to NSLog into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271528/how-to-nslog-into-a-file) to create my own NSLog.

in iFob-Prefix.pch:

```
    #import "Log.h"
    #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    #define NSLog( args, ... )      _Log(@"Prefixs", __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, args);
    #else
    #define NSLog( args, ... )
```

in Log.h

```
        @interface Log : NSObject
        void _Log(NSString *prefix, const char *file, int lineNumber, const char *funcName, NSString *format,...);

        @end
```

in Log.m

```
#import "Log.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#define PADDING_TABS 10

@implementation Log
void _Log(NSString *prefix, const char *file, int lineNumber, const char *funcName, NSString *format,...) {

    va_list ap;
    va_start (ap, format);
    format = [format stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",format]
                                           arguments:ap];

    msg = formatJsonData(msg);

    va_end (ap);
    fprintf(stderr,"\n%s[%30s:%4d] - %s",[prefix UTF8String], [[[NSString stringWithUTF8String:file] lastPathComponent]UTF8String] , lineNumber, [msg UTF8String]);
    append(msg);

}
```

I got error every time when I pass  [<"object"> description]  into the log.
Like:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = rasEngine.managedObjectContext ;
    NSLog(@"context: %@",[context description])
```

error:
 [image: error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `NSLog( args, ... )` to `NSLog( args... )`

otherwise you are calling something like `NSLog(@"content %@");` without pass the object