# NSLog will NOT output from the ViewController class, but WILL from the AppDelegate class. iOS:Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

I am facing a strange issue from last few days. `NSLog` doesn't show anything in the debugger area. This issue is strange because `NSLog` is working perfectly upto `appDelegate`. I have some `NSLog` statements in `didFinishLaunching` method and these logs are shown in the console. Any `NSLog` statements after this point is simply skipped.

I searched for any redefinitions like `#define NSLog(...)`. But i couldn't find any.
Then I checked if the console is deactivated. Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd></kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, but it didn't help.

Also, the debugger is set to show *All output*.

If the app crashes,it normally used to show something like : `Terminating app...Reason:..`. But now the app simply crashes. It doesn't show anything. So, after *appDelegate*, the console is dead.

What can be the issue? Anybody faced this before?

**EDIT:**
The following is a similar issue. 
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/nslog-will-not-output-from-the-viewcontroller-class-but-will-from-the-appdelegate-class

Comment: Can you share screen shot of console?

Comment: @AayushKatiyar what code are you talking about?The app works normal.It simply skips the NSLog statements after launching.It will work perfectly upto appDelegate.

Comment: Add exception break point in Xcode and try again

Comment: @TarunSeera it simply skips the NSLog statements.I tried adding a breakpoint before and after an nslog statement.Nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually logging something? Which libraries are you using?

Comment: `NSLog` could also be redefined by a global function in Swift?

Comment: @Sulthan I have logs for all apis that I am calling.None of them are working now.Googles IMA and admob are the two framework I have added recently.

Comment: also,I am working in objectve C.not swift.

Comment: Do you have anything like this in your .pch file? #define NSLog ,this basically replaces NSLog with nothing when it's compiled.

Comment: There is only one .pch file for SDWebImage framework.There I don't see anything like this.

Comment: When you say nothing happens on a breakpoint, do you mean it doesn't break, or does it break but it doesn't print the log?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez it doesn't print anything.`NSLog(@"HELLO WORLD");` will be simply skipped.

Comment: Yes, but do the breakpoints pause the execution or are they skipped?

Comment: Please add breakpoint at line that has `NSLog` command, to make sure that line is executed.
I think your app is crashed so your NSLog doesn't show anything?

Comment: @matiboo I am not complaining about the crash.That I mentioned to say that the console is dead after appdelegate.it shows nothing.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez The line is executed. breakpoints pause the execution.

Comment: @abhi1992 so please add breakpoints like i said in other files ?

Comment: The line is executed.It was all working before two days.

Comment: If the line is skipped, that most likely it is not there. Look into the preprocessed output (you can open it using of the Xcode menus). Check that `NSLog` is really there.

Comment: xcode  menus?it is working in appdelegate right.I didn't get your point.

Comment: May be this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271528/how-to-nslog-into-a-file

Comment: This happens only for one project.That is strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to print the logs in AppDelegate and if this issue comes after  the app has launched,then the issue should be in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. Just check for any unwanted code inside this method.I had the same issue.

Comment: Yeah,I had some code inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ` to generate a .log file.The code is working fine when I removed that.