# How to redirect NSLog to 3rd-party log destination in swift project?

Tags: swift, nslog

I have a project cite 3rd-party frameworks. in which it  use `NSLog`. I'd like to redirect `NSLog` to other destination(say [Dotzu](https://github.com/remirobert/Dotzu/))

Is it possible to override NSLog in my project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect NSLog to File in Swift not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41680004/redirect-nslog-to-file-in-swift-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot overwrite it, because it is a function, not a method. However, `NSLog()` additionally writes to `stderr` under some conditions as stated in the discussion of `NSLogv()`, which is called by `NSLog()`:

> Logs an error message to the Apple System Log facility (see man 3 asl). If the STDERR_FILENO file descriptor has been redirected away from the default or is going to a tty, it will also be written there. If you want to direct output elsewhere, you need to use a custom logging facility.

So simply redirect `STDERR_FILENO` using `freopen()`.

Comment: Thank you, you solved my first problem, but how to direct it to [Dotzu](https://github.com/remirobert/Dotzu/)? It seems like there is no way?

Comment: Doesn't it do itself? There is an option: Opening a "pseudo file" and redirect to this. However, Dotzu would have to support it. I do not know Dotzu.

Comment: I doesn't. Ok, thank you for your answer. I'll try it