# Save RestKit request and response to a text file Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I did some research and found that is possible to show a log in the console using two lines of code:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace); 
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

But I want to save the request and response to a text file.

Comment: what exactly do you wanna do ? Its not really clear

Comment: actually I use restkit to contact to server and get response.in console log it prints the request object and response object. I want to save those request and response body to a text file .so that I can use it to analyze if there are any timeout issues etc.

Comment: This Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271528/how-to-nslog-into-a-file might help you