# Reading previous app logs from installed App via TestFlight without Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, testflight

I have developed an App and distributed it via TestFlight, I am just wondering if it is possible to retrieve older app logs using some utility. I am aware of using Xcode/ Console to stream live device logs - but I have no interest in seeing live logs. The logging function I am using in my app is NSLog.

Thanks.

Comment: `NSLog` is a function, not a framework. Logs created with it are logged to the console and not saved to memory, so you can't get older logs.

Comment: What are the options to log to memory ?

Comment: As for your last question, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271528/how-to-nslog-into-a-file