# How to bind (redirect ?) NSLog's output to an IBOutlet, etc?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos, nslog

Think i/o redirection, a lá `2>&1`, but not as cryptic / annoying…  Basically.. if you're debugging something.. Console messages back in the IDE aren't very useful. So I thought..  OK, I'll just redirect NSLog, `stdout`- style.  But how?  I'm a **nincompoop** in the `C` department, but I'm *sure* you eager beavers will jump in with some **simple** `#define` - or other pre-processor idiosyncrasy -  perfect for just this type of occasion. So, in pictures…

[image: the attempt]

No errors. Logs to console AOK, as seen below.

[image: Normal LOG, aok]

But as I had feared.. No bound output, except for `%@`.

[image: No dice in my window]

How, may I simply, either synthesize an IBOutlet instance of NSLog, or otherwise capture it for further abuse and misuse?

∀Ⓛ∃✖

Comment: By the way, what's your font and theme? love it :)

Comment: @sunnyxx UbuntuMono-Bold.  The last font you'll ever need.

Comment: Thanks so much, a little bit thin

Answer (score 5):

NSLog simply writes to `stderr`, so you can use the `freopen` function to log the output to a file as described here:

[Logging to a file on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202299/logging-to-a-file-on-the-iphone)

Once you have the data in a file, you could read from that file and put the results in a view.

If you want more of a real-time view than polling a file could provide, you might be able to redirect `stderr` to a pipe using the `NSPipe` class.  I've never tried it, but this link might help:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/110139-redirect-stderr-to-nstextview.html