# Writing NSLog to a local file on the device (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, local, nslog

I have an application that currently outputs through NSLog for certain things, and I want to have those outputs be written to a local file.

I have been using this article:
[Save NSLog into a Local File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871855/save-nslog-into-a-local-file)

It was answered by stack overflow user Josiah, so thank you for that Josiah!

I want to use the code presented in the linked question, but I am not sure of how to format the self created logIt method to replace the NSLog calls.

Can anyone help a  fledgling iOS coder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably using an external library like Cocoa Lumberjack for example would be the simplest solution. You can configure file loggers easily there, set up log file retention policy, etc.

https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack

Comment: I don't know that it would be the *simplest* solution. CocoaLumberjack can actually be a bit of a challenge to get your head around if you want anything other than the default behavior, but it's quite useful, and already finished and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the contents of the **NSLog** into the method **logIt:** as an **NSString**. You can simply pass it into the **stringWithFormat:** class method of **NSString** and then pass on the returned value.

An example would be something like -

replace

```
NSLog(@"message with %f value", aFloat);
```

with

```
[self logIt:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"message with %f value", aFloat]];
```